# Как в MS Sql Server создать тип записи timestump, что б значение при вставке вставлялось в виде UNIX времени?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, unixtimestamp

Как в MS SQL Server создать тип записи timestamp, что б значение при вставке вставлялось в виде UNIX времени?
По умолчанию если ставлю тип timestamp -там пишется бред(то-есть версия строки и что-то там ещё), но явно не нужный timestamp. Как установить timestamp либо тогда на c# сгенерировать и вставить как int?

Comment: А зачем? почему не использовать либо `rowversion` либо `datetime2`?

Answer (score 4):

Объявляете [функцию конвертации datetime в UNIX Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837268/1988244):

```
CREATE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
@ctimestamp datetime
)
RETURNS integer
AS 
BEGIN
  /* Function body */
  declare @return integer

  SELECT @return = DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, @ctimestamp)

  return @return
END
```

и выставляете ее в качестве дефолтного значения для колонки типа int:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Table_1_Timestamp DEFAULT dbo.UNIX_TIMESTAMP(GETUTCDATE()) FOR TimestampColumn
```